# certificate created by elasticsearch-certutil is not usable in production?

Tags: elasticsearch, certificate

I've followed instrunction on https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/7.4/get-started-docker.html#get-started-docker-tls to setup basic authentication

The doc creates certificate by

```
  bash -c '
    yum install -y -q -e 0 unzip;
    if [[ ! -f /certs/bundle.zip ]]; then
      bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --silent --pem --in config/certificates/instances.yml -out /certs/bundle.zip;
      unzip /certs/bundle.zip -d /certs;
    fi;
    chown -R 1000:0 /certs
  '
```

It seems I can connect to the `https` endpoint from localhost only, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes elastic can generate CSR for sign it in Public CA or corporate CA or it issues just selfsign certificate.
So if you issued self-sign - sure you can use it in production but with "no veryfy certificate" option. Otherwise you can buy or order free certificate for example letsencrypt.

Comment: I just want to prevent some unknown person accessing and messing with my indexes , I want to setup a password. https is not a requirement.. 

`no verify certificate` would allow me to do that?
(would I be using http or https in that case?)

Comment: if you don't need any ssl layer - you shoul use only "xpack.security.enabled: true" option in your elasticsearch.yml. but when it is not covered by ssl - someone can sniff your password via network - because it will be transferred in plain text over network.

Comment: I don't think you can turn on basic auth with `xpack.seucity.enabled` without turning on ssl in cluster mode.. https://discuss.elastic.co/t/enable-x-pack-without-ssl-on-kibana-and-elasticsearch-using-helm-chart/186956/16

Comment: xpack.security.enabled is enabled basic authentication to elasticsearch. you don't need to configure encryption for http or for transport. but you can if you wish. it is three different parts.